# How do I select an IMG inside a TD?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate, selector

This is my jQuery code...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("gallery", Image).hover(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);
    });
  });
</script>
```

My HTML...

```
<table class="gallery">
  <tr>
    <td>                
      <img src="photo.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS...

```
.gallery img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

I want -any- image I have in the table "gallery" to change the opacity to 1.0 when I perform a mouse hover. I'm certain my syntax is wrong. Can I do what I want to do? I do not want to specify classes for each image.

Comment: jQuery selectors closely follow the CSS selector syntax. If in doubt, treat it as if you were writing a css selector in your style sheet.

Comment: That's actually a very helpful comment. I'll definitely keep that in mind in the future, thank you!

Comment: Any selector that is more than "#theid" ".theclass" or "theTagName" gets passed through to `document.querySelectorAll()`, as long as the selector doesn't contain any jQuery custom selectors. Therefore, in most cases, it literally is the same syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a class with the `.` at the start, then anything after that in your quotes will be children elements:

```
$(".gallery img").hover(function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with javascript, but it's far easier doing it with css. Just add:

```
.gallery img {
     opacity:0.5;
     transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.gallery img:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Because I want it to animate, not just change opacity.

Comment: Thank you but I would be worried about lack of browser support for transition (IE9 and below).

Comment: This is a good answer and probably the easiest but transitions are not fully supported across browsers.

Comment: I like to think of transitions as frills to usability, so its not necessarily needed to make use of the website or product (for UX) but is a bonus. The fallback isn't too shabby either and doesn't hurt flow.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("gallery", Image).hover(function(){
```

to this:

```
$(".gallery img").hover(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

[SHOW DEMO](http://jsbin.com/emObOqO/1/edit)

jQuery

```
$(document).on({

    mouseenter: function () {

        $(".gallery img").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);  

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

        $(".gallery img").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 800);  
    }
}, "#gal");
```

HTML

```
<table id="gal" class="gallery">
    <tr>
       <td>                
          <img src="img">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.gallery img {

    opacity: 0.5;
}
```